# Populate VB6 ListBox with single instruction

Tags: arrays, vb6, listbox

In VB6 I can't seem to be able to do that:

```
myListBox.List = listContentStringArrray
```

VB is complaining with a compile error saying "Argument not optional", obviously because `.List(index)` requires, well, an index.

The following code works in VBA:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim result() As String
    ReDim result(0)
    result(0) = "hello"
    ReDim Preserve result(1)
    result(1) = "world"

    ListBox1.List = result

End Sub
```

Looking at the *object browser* I found that the ListBox in VBA is really `MSForms.ListBox` and in VB6 it's `VB.ListBox`.

The VBA ListBox's *List* property is declared as `Property List([pvargIndex], [pvargColumn])` and in VB6 it's `Property List(Integer) As String`, which is where my problem comes from.

Is there a way to "swap" `VB.ListBox` for `MSForms.ListBox` in an existing code base without breaking anything, or `MSForms` was designed for use only in VBA as the "VB" library isn't included in VBA? If I reference `FM20.dll` in my VB6 project, I can see the `MSForms.ListBox` in the object browser, but not in the toolbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use `Forms 2.0` controls in VB6 application. For instance, it is one of ways to get controls that support Unicode (see [How To Read and Display UNICODE String on Visual Basic Form](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193540) KB article).

> If I reference FM20.dll in my VB6 project, I can see the
>   MSForms.ListBox in the object browser, but not in the toolbox.

To add the controls to the toolbox you have to add `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library` via **Project | Components** menu item (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):
[image]

But, frankly, if all you need is an ability to 'populate VB6 ListBox with single instruction' it is a *huge* overkill. Just code a routine that does it for regular VB6 `ListBox` and you're done.

Also keep in mind that Forms 2.0 controls are **not** redistributable. From [INFO: Usage and Redistribution of FM20.DLL](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q224305) KB:

> The Fm20.dll is NOT redistributable. You must have an application such
>   as Microsoft Office 97 on the target system that installs Fm20.dll as
>   part of its setup... In any case, you may not distribute the Fm20.dll
>   as part of your setup, even if you purchase the Microsoft Office
>   Developer Edition product.
>
> As an alternative to having your end users
>   install Microsoft Office, you can have them freely download and
>   install the Microsoft ActiveX Control Pad, which also installs the
>   Fm20.dll.

Comment: `Just code a routine that does it for regular VB6 ListBox and you're done` - as in, iterate the whole array and add one item at a time anyway? It's not really a *need* per se, and I don't want to go through the pain of manually swapping all `ListBox` controls for their FM20.dll counterpart. So I guess I'll just stick to good ol' `For` loop. Nice answer BTW :)

Comment: Don't use Forms 2 - it will crash your VB6 program. [Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241245/EN-US/) "FM20.DLL is known to have many problems when used with Visual Basic and other developer products. Its use is neither recommended nor supported in any Visual Studio product."